# Tags request: rdf, sparql, owl, rdfs

Tags: feature-request, tags

When I search I find multiple questions containing "sparql" or other terms.
Here is my request for creating following tags: rds, sparql, owl, rdfs - all related with graph databases, datasets and their analysis.

Answer (score 3):

If you find a question that you believe could use this tag, and do not have the reputation to add it, then comment on the question and I will add it.

Comment: How will you discover that comment? Are you reading _every_ question? ;-)

Comment: It should notify me if you @-mention me